# Error printing xml nodes using \n

Tags: php

I want to print each element of an xml document on a new line without using `<br/>`.

Here is the code I'm using but it skips the "\n". Please help

```
<?php
$xmlstr= '<Address><to>James</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Please check your mail.</body></Address>' ;     
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlstr);
echo $xml->getName() . "\n";

foreach($xml->children() as $child)
  {
  echo $child->getName() . ": " . $child . "\n";
  }
?>
```

The required output:

```
Address
to: James
from: Jani
heading: Reminder
body: Please check your mail.
```

Comment: if you are looking this in a web browser, it will skip new lines, unless you don't send Content-type text/plain header

Comment: so ,what I'm doin is correct?except that the browser doesn't display it correctly?how can i send Content-type text/plain header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want HTML, simply follow @Darhazer's suggestion and write this before echoing anything:

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

The browser will then interpret the text as plain text.

---

<strike>I'm assuming you're using HTML here. The issue you're facing here is that whitespace is not meaningful in HTML. It's your markup that can affect how it is going to render.</strike>

<strike>This looks a lot like an unordered list, so it's probably the way to go. Simply enclose each line into `<li>`, and add CSS so that bullets are not displayed:</strike>

<strike>HTML:</strike>

```
<ul class="mail">
    <li>to: James</li>
    <li>from: Jani</li>
    <li>heading: Reminder</li>
    <li>body: Please check your mail</li>
</ul>
```

<strike>CSS:</strike>

```
ul.mail { list-style-type: none }
```

Comment: @hina_naaz I meant "since you're writing HTML using PHP". The header comment is PHP, and the example HTML was what you would have written using PHP. I edited my answer anyway.

Comment: hey, thanks it solved the problem!i should have asked it earlier!jus banging my head over this issue for soo long!thnx